# How do I use randrange() on a random seed in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So, I was asked in class to use the specific random seed 237. But I don't know how to properly implement it. For example, this is my code. *in python 3*. 
In this example I'm basically throwing m number of dice with k number of sides and trying to return a tuple of m length.

```
import random
rng=random.seed(237)
# create random number generator

def throwDice(m, k):
    x = 0
    L = []
    while x < m :
        die = rng.randrange(1,k+1)
        L.append(die)
        x+=1
    return print(tuple(L))
throwDice(11,5)
```

Yet, the command prompt keeps showing the error

```
die = rng.randrange(1,k+1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'randrange'`
```

Could I get an explanation of what's wrong :(

Comment: The seed is basically telling your random number generator how to be random (With the same seed it will always pick the same numbers). What you want is to call it like: `die = random.randrange(1, k+1)`

Answer (score 3):

`random.seed` returns `None`, so in

```
rng=random.seed(237)
```

`rng` gets set to `None`. And then you try to call

```
None.randrange(1,k+1)
```

in your function, and obviously that's not going to work.

Also, the `print` function returns `None`, so

```
return print(tuple(L))
```

will return `None`. You don't want that.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
import random

random.seed(237)

# create random number generator
def throwDice(m, k):
    L = []
    for x in range(m):
        die = random.randrange(1, k+1)
        L.append(die)
    return tuple(L)

print(throwDice(11, 5))
```

**output**

```
(5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1)
```

On Python 2, you get this output:

```
(4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1)
```

---

I've used a `for` loop to perform the desired number of dice rolls, that's better than using a `while` loop and "manually" counting the rolls with `x += 1`. We aren't actually using the value of `x` in that loop, and it's a common convention in Python to use `_` as the name for the loop variable in that situation, i.e.,

```
for _ in range(m):
```

FWIW, we can write this function in a compact fashion by using a generator expression:

```
def throwDice(m, k):
    return tuple(random.randrange(1, k+1) for _ in range(m))
```

---

In some situations we need multiple independent random number streams. We can easily do that by creating an instance of the `Random` class; the constructor of the class takes the seed as an optional argument.

```
import random

# Create a random number generator, and seed it
myrandom = random.Random(237)

def throwDice(m, k):
    L = []
    for _ in range(m):
        die = myrandom.randrange(1, k+1)
        L.append(die)
    return tuple(L)
```

Comment: With Python 3.6 could use `random.choices` and save the explicit loop i think

Comment: @Chris_Rands True, but as this is homework, the OP may be required to use `randrange`. TBH, I keep forgetting that `choices` exists. :) For this task, I'd probably use `randint(1, k)`.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple: in the second line, you are creating an object, called `rng`, which is the return value of `random.seed(237)`. It just so happens that `random.seed` always returns `None`. So later in your code, when you try `rng.randrange`, Python is going to look up an attribute named `randrange` of the `rng` object. But the `rng` object is `None`, which doesn't have a `randrange` attribute.

What you really meant is just `random.randrange(1, k+1)` instead of `rng.randrange(1, k+1)`.

Comment: Ok, so if I import the seed, I don't have to refer back to it within my code? I can just use random.randrange() ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes. You can try this yourself by setting the seed, then asking for a random number (or range). If you then re-set the seed to the same value, and ask for another random number (or range) it should be the same.